# TelemteryChannel in ApplicationInsights of Java web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, azure-application-insights

How do we add a custom Telemetry channel in ApplicationInsights.xml file of a java application?

Is it something like

```
<TelemetryChannel type="com.test.MyChannel" />
```

I have added this line. But looks like it is not getting invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your class should implement TelemetryChannel
2. The tag you should have in your ApplicationInsights.xml file:

> `<Channel type="com.test.MyChannel" />`

Comment: Yes. I had tried this. But I gets error as AI: ERROR 06-02-2017 11:00, 12: Failed to create com.test.MyChannel, com.test.MyChannel.<init>(java.util.Map).   And it is not sending the message

Comment: There should be constructor with a Map. After that it is working.           public MyChannel(Map<String, String> initMap){
  
 }  Example is here https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/channel/concrete/inprocess/InProcessTelemetryChannel.java

Answer (score 0):

Once the javaSDK is installed you should be able to call API from your code. TelemetryConfiguration.TelemetryChannel. Some information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-get-started) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling)

Comment: Thanks, that is something which I already did. TelemetryConfiguration telmetryConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.getActive();
  telmetryConfig.setChannel(new MyChannel());  I was looking for xml configuration similar to that of dotnet .config file